# How to manage dictionaries inside html Django

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, jinja2

So I'm loading a dictionary to HTML but I'm having some trouble getting the `second_value` from the dictionary (`{'first_value': 'second_value'}`).

The dictionary I'm parsing is this:

```
{1: 'Bayer', 2: 'Celgene Europe Limited', 3: 'Celgene Europe Limited'}
```

My code inside HTML:

```
{% for x in drugs %}
    <a href="{{ x }}"><li>{{ drugs.x }}</li></a>
{% endfor %}
```

And what is displaying in the HTML is:

```
<ul style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">

        <a href="1"><li></li></a>

        <a href="2"><li></li></a>

        <a href="3"><li></li></a>

</ul>
```

What is supposed to happen is the number to be displayed in the `href` and the drug name to be displayed inside the `<li></li>` tags.
For example:

```
<a href="1"><li>Bayer</li></a>
```

Comment: drugs is `dictionary` or `list`? You are iterating it means `list` and also using `drugs.x` means `dictionary`

Comment: You can't use `drugs` in a `for loop`. I suggest you to go through basic python tutorial.

Comment: @Hisham___Pak In pure python I know how its done but for some stupid reason my mind stopped working and I cant find a way to make it work in html

Comment: Note that a `<li>` element cannot be a child of an `<a>` element. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML template to:

```
{% for key, val in drugs.items %}
    <li><a href="{{ key }}">{{ val }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

When looping through a dict, the key and corresponding value can be retrieved at the same time using the dict's `items()` method.

Note that a `<li>` element cannot be the child of an `<a>` element ([reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/grouping-content.html#the-li-element)). I have fixed this issue by moving your `<a>` elements inside the `<li>` elements.